# Time step in Adam optimizer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement Adam optimizer for my neural network (everything written from scratch).

I have it implemented, but there is one thing I am not sure about. When is the time step incremented?

What I mean is, is it increased it after every minibatch? Do I increase it after every epoch? Do I reset calculated previous moments and time step after every epoch?

I am trying all the options, and everything yields different results, so I am not sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Adam optimiser has nothing to do with neural networks, consequently the way it is defined is in terms of a standard iterative process

```
theta_{t+1}, state_{t+1} = adam(loss, theta_t, state_t)
```

Note that there are no "batches", "epochs" or anything. Each time you update your weights, you update your statistics (state).

If you now happen to use a mini batch to estimate your gradient, and update your weights based on that, this is when your stats update too. if you decide to use full gradient, this is when the state updates, and so on.